# Simple python code can't execute with invalid syntax

Tags: python

The following script is not executable. Did some search and I don't think there is any error.

```
for i in range(1, length):
    itchat.send("జ్ఞా", toUserName=friends[i]['UserName'])
    print(f'检测到第{i}位好友: {str(friends[i]["NickName"]).center(20, " ")}')
```

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Post the error and other relevant info, as ``friends``

Comment: fstrings are usable only in python 3.x, if you are new to python i would suggest using `'{}'.format(var)` format function

Comment: My terminal shown 2.7 but i was execute via python launcher 3.6

Comment: try to run python with the python3 command - some OS versions have python point to 2.7 and python3 to 3.x

Comment: 23333 Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in range(1, length):
    itchat.send("జ్ఞా", toUserName=friends[i]['UserName'])
    print('检测到第{}位好友: {}'.format(i, str(friends[i]["NickName"]).center(20, " ")))
```